# Complex type argument for TFS build definition workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I currently have a build template that takes multiple arguments "A", "B", "C", defined like that :

```
<x:Property Name="A" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
<x:Property Name="B" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="C" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
```

And I would like to be able to replace these three arguments by an array of one object "D" that has 3 properties : A (string), B (bool), C (string).
So I created a "D" class in which I created the 3 properties (should I add annotations over them ? like the InArgument thing?), and replaced the 3 XAML lines by

```
<x:Property Name="D" Type="InArgument(y:DComplexType[])" />
```

Then I updated the "Metadata" argument using the "Process Parameter Metadata Editor" window, and the problem is that I don't know what should I enter in the "Editor" field to get an editor similar to what is displayed when editing the "AgentSettings" type for example.

And I checked-in the new XAML file.

The problem is that when I create a new build definition editor does not let me edit the attributes like if it was not able to generate the edition form automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to inherit from `DialogPropertyValueEditor` & `Workflowelementdialog`

> For `DialogPropertyValueEditor`

You have sample here WF_WCF_Samples\WF\Basic\Designer\PropertyGridExtensibility\cs

link : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en

> For `Workflowelementdialog`

link : http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.activities.presentation.workflowelementdialog(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=KSqGUr2NJqSS0QX60YCwCA&usg=AFQjCNFO4qdV_RJIpilewDpaSEzUbCegiA&bvm=bv.56643336,d.d2k

Comment: I do not understand why do I need to inherit from something since I'm using a complex type composed of simple types that all have standard editors (I guess ?). On MSDN I saw a post from someone using this : "    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]", but it does not seem to fix my problem.

Comment: inherit in order to use an specific type, because your complex type is not working, custommize your layout